# How to drop NA's out of the summarise(count = n()) function in R?

Tags: r, count

I have a dataset containing 4 organisation units (org_unit) with different number of participants and 2 Questions (Q1,Q2) on a 2-degree scale (1:2). I want to know how many people per unit answered the respective question with [1] and divide them by the total number of participants / unit.

```
Org_unit <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4)
Q1 <-  c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
Q2 <- c(-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9)
```

The problem is, my Q2 only consists of [-9] which stands for non-response. I therefore assigned NA to [-9].

```
DF <- data.frame(Org_unit, Q1, Q2)
DF[DF == -9] <- NA
DF

   Org_unit Q1 Q2
1         1  1 NA
2         1  2 NA
3         1  1 NA
4         1  2 NA
5         2  1 NA
6         2  2 NA
7         2  1 NA
8         3  2 NA
9         3  1 NA
10        4  2 NA
```

Next I calculated the proportion of people who answered Q1 with [1], which works fine.

```
prop_q1 <- DF %>%
 group_by(Org_unit) %>%
 summarise(count = n(), 
        prop = mean(Q1 == 1))

prop_q1
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Org_unit count  prop
   <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1        1     4 0.5  
2        2     3 0.667
3        3     2 0.5  
4        4     1 0
```

when i run the same code for Q2 however, I get the same amount of members per unit (count = c(1,2,3,4), although nobody answered the question and I don't want them to be registered as participants, since they technically didn't participate in the study.

```
prop_q2 <- DF %>%
  group_by(Org_unit) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), 
        prop = mean(Q2 == 1))
prop_q2
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Org_unit count  prop
     <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1        1     4    NA
2        2     3    NA
3        3     2    NA
4        4     1    NA
```

Is there a way to calculate the right amount of members per unit when facing NA's? [-9]
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would

```
prop_q2 <- DF %>%
  filter(!is.na(Q2)) %>%
  group_by(Org_unit) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), 
        prop = mean(Q2 == 1))
```

do the job?

Comment: there is no data available in the table,"# A tibble: 0 x 3" unfortunately

Comment: The OP needs the data to remain in the dataset, so filtering won't work

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want to do this across multiple columns, I think that using `across()` within the `dplyr` verbs will be better for you. I explain the solution below.

```r
Org_unit <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4)
Q1 <-  c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
Q2 <- c(1,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9) #Note one response

df <- tibble(Org_unit, Q1, Q2)

df %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with("Q"), ~na_if(., -9))) %>%
    group_by(Org_unit) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("Q"),
        list(
            N = ~sum(!is.na(.)),
            prop = ~sum(. == 1, na.rm = TRUE)/sum(!is.na(.)))
    )) 
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  Org_unit  Q1_N Q1_prop  Q2_N Q2_prop
*    <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <int>   <dbl>
1        1     4   0.5       1       1
2        2     3   0.667     0     NaN
3        3     2   0.5       0     NaN
4        4     1   0         0     NaN
```

First, we take the data frame (which I created as a tibble) and substitute `NA` for all values that equal `-9` for all columns that start with a capital "Q". This converts all question columns to have `NA`s in place of `-9`s.

Second, we group by the organizational unit and then summarize using two functions. The first sums all values where the response to the question is not NA. The string `_N` will be appended to columns with these values. The second calculates the proportion and will have `_prop` appended to the values.

Comment: When I increase the 3 vectors by 1 to add another individual of org_unit 4, who answered q2 with [1], Q2_n indeed counts the correct number of [1] answers , but I also get NA for q2_prop, although there is at least 1 Person of organizational unit 4 who has answered the right question. Do you know why that's the case?

Comment: Yes! The `sum()` function returns `NA` if any items are present in the vector. Setting the `na.rm` parameter to `TRUE` gets rid of `NA` values before calculating the sum. I fixed the example above (note that `Q2_prop` now returns `NaN` rather than `NA`, which shouldn't affect you -- if it does you can substitute those back to NA values).